# cannot ping by hostname but can ping by IP - Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-dns

We have a Spark master node on a Google Cloud Dataproc cluster, which we want to connect by Hostname and NOT the Internal IP.
**We want to** connect/ping these VMs from one another.
**Rationale:** When we drop/create any of the VMs/Clusters, the internal IP changes, but we dont want to change bunch of connection strings everytime.

GCLOUD command line lists the Master node VM:

```
vn524i0@m-c02zf1nylvdt ~$ gcloud compute instances list | grep anvil
anvil-dataproc-m           us-east1-a  custom-16-65536               10.22.162.40                RUNNING
```

From another GCP VM (in same region) when I try to ping the VM using the internal IP, I am able to (so ICMP is enabled):

```
vn524i0@m-c02zf1nylvdt ~$ ping 10.22.162.40 -c 1
PING 10.22.162.40 (10.22.162.40): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.22.162.40: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=140.232 ms

--- 10.22.162.40 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
```

But when I try to ping by hostname, I get Unknown Host error:

```
vn524i0@m-c02zf1nylvdt ~$ ping anvil-dataproc-m
ping: cannot resolve anvil-dataproc-m: Unknown host
```

I've followed the global & Zonal DNS guide and used the hostname pattern suggested by Google as per [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#zonal-dns).

zonal DNS hostname style:

```
vn524i0@m-c02zf1nylvdt ~$ ping anvil-dataproc-m.us-east1-a.c.PROJECT_NAME.internal -c 1
ping: cannot resolve anvil-dataproc-m.us-east1-a.c.PROJECT_NAME.internal: Unknown host
```

global DNS hostname style:

```
vn524i0@m-c02zf1nylvdt ~$ ping anvil-dataproc-m.c.PROJECT_NAME.internal -c 1
ping: cannot resolve anvil-dataproc-m.c.PROJECT_NAME.internal: Unknown host
```

Any guidance on how to connect / ping/nslookup by hostname and not depend upon internal IP please?

Comment: Since you are able to ping the private IP address, you must have a VPN or similar configured. The next step is to configure your VPN to use the VPC's DNS server. However, a quick solution is to add the hostname and IP address in your local system's **/etc/hosts** file. https://help.nexcess.net/how-to-find-the-hosts-file-on-my-mac

Comment: Actually we want to connect from one GCP VM to this master VM, not from Local.

Comment: Edit your question and clarify exactly what you are trying to do. Mentioning your Mac only confuses the question.